# Amazon EC2 error: unable to generate a temporary class (result=1) error CS2001

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to get tags from Amazon EC2:

```
using (client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonEC2Client(accessKeyID, secretAccessKeyID))
{
     DescribeTagsRequest request = new DescribeTagsRequest().WithFilter(
         new Filter().WithName("key").WithValue(new string[] { "domain" }), 
         new Filter().WithName("resource-type").WithValue(new string[] { "instance" }));           

     DescribeTagsResponse responce = client.DescribeTags(request);  //**error**
}
```

Error text:

```
Message: Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Windows\TEMP\03eg1ztl.0.cs' could not be found
error CS2008: No inputs specified
```

I found two solutions: give the account access to the temp directory and use sgen.exe for AWSSDK.dll

When i am trying to used sgen.exe for AWSSDK.dll, i get error:

```
Types "Amazon.RDS.Model.VpcSecurityGroupMembership" 
and "Amazon.Redshift.Model.VpcSecurityGroupMembership" 
use the name of the type XML "VpcSecurityGroupMembership" from namespace "". 
Use the attributes of XML, to set the type of a unique name and / or namespace XML.
```

Help me please!

Answer (score 1):

You should consider trying version 2 of the AWS SDK (http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/#version2). Version 1 of the SDK uses XSLT for EC2 and I have seen this cause permissions issues like this before. Your code would look like this using version 2.

```
using (client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonEC2Client(accessKeyID, secretAccessKeyID))
{
    DescribeTagsRequest request = new DescribeTagsRequest
    {
        Filters = new List<Filter>
        {
            new Filter{ Name = "key", Values = new List<string>{"domain"}},
            new Filter{ Name = "resource-type", Values = new List<string>{"instance"}}
        }
    };

    DescribeTagsResponse responce = client.DescribeTags(request);  //**error**
}
```